# simple url rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can i add to a .htaccess file so that the following rules don't apply if the url contains a certain variable?

```
# Options All
# Options -Indexes
#
# RewriteEngine on
#
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
# RewriteRule (.*)$ /shared/php/v1/hotmusiclink.php?p=$1 [L]

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```

e.g. the above should redirect all url's to hotmusiclink.php, unless they have the string ?code=s0mec0de in the url

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **RewriteCond** to make any given rewrite not be applied.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !code=s0mec0de
RewriteRule ^.*$ /hotmusiclink.php
```

Play with that until it works.